# scrollable layout not working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm a beginner in android. I'm creating a example phonebook using eclipse. i have few edit texts and a set off buttons in my layout.but when I run the project I can't see the buttons in the bottom of the layout, so I enclosed my main linear layout in a Scrollview. but after linear layout has become much bigger in height. i tried to resize it in the xml file but it is not working right after resizing the layout it automatically resizes in to the previous size. here's my code if anyone can help me.little help is highly appreciated.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="466dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="com.nadusha.phonebook.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Info"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/nameTextLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    <requestFocus />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobileNoTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" >


    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/homeNoTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E-Mail "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


       <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ViewContact"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</Linearlayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try changing the height of scroll view to match_parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set ScrollView layoutWeight to 1 and its height to 0. This will ensure that your scrollview will take only remaining space on screen. Here is example of my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/menoLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/emergencySMSMeno"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/menoEdit"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pohlavieLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/emergencySMSPohlavie"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerPohlavie"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vekLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/emergencySMSVek"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/vekEdit"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vahaLabel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/emergencySMSVaha"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/vahaEdit"
                    style="@style/editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/alergieLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/emergencySMSAlergie"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/alergieEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chorobyLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/emergencySMSChoroby"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/chorobyEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/zraneniaLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/emergencySMSZranenie"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/zraneniaEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="3"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/polohaLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/emergencySMSAktualnaPoloha"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/polohaEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/odoslatButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zrusitButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/emergencySMSZrusit"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It shows scrollView and two buttons bellow it. I am not exactly sure what you want to do but as far as I can see you are doint it wrong. ScrollView can take only one child element but you have set scrollview as your main parent but then you put more child inside it.

Also you are doing another mistake. You dont need to use linear layouts (in most cases) if they have only one child. It is bad for performance.

Comment: It worked. thanks a lot. I'll be thankful if you can gimme a brief about the issue of using linear layouts with one child

Comment: this site explains it in deep https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html and if you want more information on how to imporve UI performance then visit this https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing

```
android:layout_height="466dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: i tried all of them. but it didn't work as i expected

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of the attribute layout_height to match_parent so that the ScrollView take up the whole screen and hence enable scrolling. The correct code is

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="com.nadusha.phonebook.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Info"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/nameTextLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    <requestFocus />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobileNoTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" >


    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/homeNoTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E-Mail "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


       <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ViewContact"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</Linearlayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```